# What form of suru is the "されていた" part of 支配されていた?

Tags: conjugations

I understand that 支配する　means to rule. So I'm guessing the "されていた" in 支配されていた is a weird form of する. Is it in passive past te-form?

Comment: What do you mean by "te-form"? Do you consider 支配している the te-form of 支配する? If so, you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost! ←「[惜]{お}しい！」 in Japanese.

The passive voice past is [支配]{しはい}された --- "was controlled".

支配されていた is passive voice past progressive --- "was being controlled"